# iOS: Firebase realtime database sub child querying

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift4

I work on iOS app that use firebase real time database, my structure as [image: following], I want to write a query that retrieve all users of a group, each user have multiple groups, and each groups have multiple users, I capable of showing all groups of one user and I want to show all other users they are belong to that group, i.e, when user choose of his groups,
How can achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the best way to deal with this is to duplicate your data. If you definitely need the structure you posted above, you can keep it and create also another one as such:

```
"groupUsers": {
  "123" : { //groupId
  "235" : { //uniqueKey for record
          userId: "567",
          userName: "Jack"
          }
          }
              }
```

To get all users in a certain group use the firebase reference:

```
`/groupUsers/${groupId}/`
```

You loop over the returned list to show values from each list item.

Comment: kwanite, I don't think that is a perfect solution, cause I have many users and each user belong to multiple groups, that mean I must duplicate user with each group that is belong to it.